# Compile small piece of code without \begin{document} with modern tools like vscode

Tags: compiling, workflow, vscode

I would like to compile piece of LaTeX code without `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (the preamble is, of course, fixed). The reason is that sometimes I only write small pieces of text and don't want to include the basic lines every time (not even with `\input`, etc.). For now the only way I know is by running shell code like the following one.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR

xelatex -interaction=batchmode \\documentclass{einfart}\\usepackage{ProjLib}\\begin{document}\\input{<filename>}\\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to do so? For example, I don't know if there is a compatible way with `latexmk`. Also, is it possible to achieve a similar effect with Visual Studio Code's extension "LaTeX Workshop"?

*(I do realize that omitting the `\begin{document}` etc. is probably not a good idea. I'm just exploring the possibilities for the workflow.)*

Comment: you can't omit the begin documnt from the latex run but your edior should be able to do that for you, auctex in emacs has been able to run latex on any selected region since the 1980's. In the background it constructs a temporary file with the document preamble and the selected region wrapprd in begin document end document.

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with using a simple shell script for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, below is the shell script I'm currently using for compile files with extension `.piece.tex`, where `.piece` is a mark to tell that this is not a complete LaTeX code file.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR

mkdir -p .aux

filename=$(ls -t *.piece.tex | head -n1)

echo "\\documentclass[use boldface, theorem in new line, simple name, theorem numbering = *]{einfart}" > .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\usepackage{ProjLib}" >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\usepackage{tikz-cd}" >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\\\begin{document}"   >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\input{$filename}"    >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\end{document}"       >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex

latexmk -xelatex -silent -output-directory=.aux -jobname=${filename%.piece.tex} .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex

mv .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.pdf ${filename%.piece.tex}.pdf
```

For example, if you have a `Document.piece.tex` with the content:

```
This is a test document.

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def1}
    \blindtext
\end{definition}

\cref{thm1,def1,thm2}

\dnf
```

Then after running the script, you shall get a `Document.pdf` looks like:

[image]

---

**Some explanations:**

The first two lines change the directory to the current one containing the shell script:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
```

Then make a `.aux` folder for storing auxiliary files.

```
mkdir -p .aux
```

The script shall now find the latest `.piece.tex` file for compilation.

```
filename=$(ls -t *.piece.tex | head -n1)
```

It will produce a same named `.temp.tex` file in the `.aux` folder for `latexmk` to work on.

```
echo "\\documentclass[use boldface, theorem in new line, simple name, theorem numbering = *]{einfart}" > .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\usepackage{ProjLib}" >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\usepackage{tikz-cd}" >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\\\begin{document}"   >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\input{$filename}"    >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
echo "\\end{document}"       >> .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
```

And finally, compile with `latexmk` and move the `.pdf` file to the current folder.

```
latexmk -xelatex -silent -output-directory=.aux -jobname=${filename%.piece.tex} .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.temp.tex
mv .aux/${filename%.piece.tex}.pdf ${filename%.piece.tex}.pdf
```